# Careers - Add Writing Rendering issue - Site within site

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Careers > My Profile > Add Writing > End up with "site within site".  This is in IE9 (Google Chrome works fine).

[image]

Comment: +1 - Got the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Jeff, this should be fixed, would you have another look?